# There is no way to use C# version 9.0 in Universal Windows Platform because it is not net core but only .net?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I started messing around with uwp from the book Head First C# (3rd Edition), and now I am a bit fired up, because it is a good framework, is seems.  I used it in the past, so I am a bit familiar with xaml.  A tutorial used a C# version 9.0 trick that was neat.  But, I could not do it in mine because the solution is an old version of C#.  I spent hours trying, but couldn't figure out how to upgrade.  Apparently because UWP is not Core and .net 5 is, that is why I can't do it.  It seems the only way to get C# version 9.0 is with .net5.
And that means, apparently, you cannot upgrade the UWP solution to C# 9.0.  Is this confirmed, for this time in life (January 1, 2023) you cannot use C# 9.0 with UWP?

Comment: Totally not true. On all points, don't know where you are getting your advice from but stop going back to them

Comment: A better post would be to show your _neet trick_ and ask how to apply that in your UWP project. But start by telling us what version of .net your UWP project is using, and what version of visual studio you have

Comment: PS, .net 5 is end of life already, .net 7 is _current_.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2022 and I am not sure what version of .net the uwp solution is running on.  I downloaded .net5 but it is not using that, I am pretty sure.  Because, like I said, it seems uwp can't use core and .net5 does use core.

Comment: UWP uses core, can't run on .net FX because it is not universal or "standard" like core is. Why not upgrade to .net 7? Get the latest build of VS2022

Comment: I am using the blank app(universal windows) template, I believe.  I consider that the uwp template.

Comment: If this is a legacy project, you might find it easier to create a new project and move the code file across. Then other research and modern code examples will be easier to follow if you are on the _current_ version.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this confirmed, for this time in life (January 1, 2023) you cannot use C# 9.0 with UWP?

C# 9 is supported only on .NET 5 and newer versions. This could be found here: [C# language versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version). But .NET 5 and newer version does not support UWP officially. So you can't use C# 9 in UWP now.